# Lowering the thermal throttling point on an Intel CPU

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, throttling

I have a laptop with the Intel i7 4700MQ processor, which I sometimes use for BOINC computing. However, in Intel XTU, I've noticed temperatures of over 80 °C for sustained periods. This temperature is higher than I'd like it to be, because I intend the CPU to be used almost 24/7 and this would affect its longevity adversely.

However, in XTU, there is no way to reset the thermal throttling point, only the power and current limit. This causes significant variation in the core temperature, depending on whether the iGPU is also in use or not when only using the power limit to control temperature, due to the iGPU taking up a large proportion of the power limit. This variation is undesirable, because if the power limit is set to keep the CPU at an acceptable temperature at all times, the CPU cores will not run at their full speed when the iGPU is working.

**TL;DR:** What I'm asking is whether there is any way to

1. Reset the thermal throttling point or
2. Set the power limits of the Core and iGP independently, instead of collectively.

For the Intel i7 4700MQ on a Windows 10 platform, without modifying firmware, so that it runs at around 75 °C full load for 24/7 BOINC computing.

Comment: The computer will be slower. What is your highest temperature. Anything under 90C is safe (but the laptop I am typing from reaches 98C during a hangouts call)

Comment: Laptops are made to handle temperatures upto 90C without any damage

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can lower the thermal throttling point using the software Throttlestop ([download link here](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/)).

The Intel default thermal throttling temperature is 100°C. ThrottleStop does not randomly change your PROCHOT temperature unless you specifically tell ThrottleStop to do this.

In Throttlestop, in the Options window, set the PROCHOT Offset value to whatever you like. Above that, check the Lock PROCHOT Offset option. If you use an offset value of 20, your CPU will start to thermal throttle at 80°C ( = 100°C - 20°C offset).